# GWT Sees enormous client window resolution on mobile

Tags: css, gwt, user-interface, screen-resolution

Upon launching GWT, I query the Window.getClientHeight() and width.  On desktop, numbers are correct for given browser window in pixels.  When I run on Android tablet or phone, numbers come out huge (e.g. 960x1400) - way bigger than what the phone's actual screen resolution is.  This causes my fixed-sized icons and other gui objects to show up really tiny on the screen forcing me to two-finger zoom in, but then inadvertent touches on the screen cause panning on the browser window which is unwanted.  Switched everything to Layout panels and all resizing works fine except that the size of the client window is huge and all icons look tiny/unusable.  Is there a way to set the zoom-level or resolution of the browser client window so a 32x32 icon looks normal when rendered on these browsers?  Maybe CSS has a control?

Comment: Mobile devices DO have resolutions of that size, eg Samsung galaxy 24 is 1080 x 1920. You should do it by device width, not resolution.

Comment: Do you know of a way to apply a "scaling factor" so you can control what Window.getClientWidth() and Window.getClientHeight() will return?  I'd like to get the device's physical width and height and divide these by the pixel width and height, and calculate a scaling factor that achieves a specific pixels per inch value.  Then, when I render a 32x32 pixel Image on any display so-scaled, they would always come out the same physical size.  Any ideas?

Comment: By the way, according to wikipedia, my Galaxy S2 has a screen resolution of 800x480 pixels, but upon launching GWT app in Chrome and using GWT Window.getWindowWidth() and Window.getWindowHeight(), obtain values: 1348x980.  Where is chrome getting these numbers from?

Comment: And my NAXA Core Android tablet, which also has 800x480 physical screen resolution, reports 1461x980.  Hmm?

Comment: The Galaxy s2 does have `800x480` but the S4 has `1080 x 1920`